# Objectos en JAVA, diferencias en asignación métodos

Tags: java, object

Agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme con la siguiente:
Tengo varios objetos cualquiera, instanciados:

```
Circulo c  = new Circulo (2.00,2.0,4.0);
Circulo c1 = new Circulo(1.9,1.0,2.0);
Circulo c2 = new Circulo(2.0,3.0,1.0);
```

Qué diferencia existe en entre las dos siguientes instrucciones:

a) `c=c1.elMayor(c2);`

b) `c=Circulo.elMayor(c1,c2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este código implemente los dos métodos ya que no se, ni como están declarados, ni que hacen los que vos pusiste. Por lo que entendí de tu pregunta, tenés duda porque hay un método que usa ´Circulo.elMayor(circulo1,circulo2)´ a diferencia de `c1.elMayor(c2)`.

```
 public class Circulo {
        private double height;
        private double width;
        private double radio;

        ...

        public boolean elMayor(Circulo c) {
            // comparar propiedades
           if(this.height > c.height && this.width > c.width && this.radio > c.radio) {
             return true;
           } else {
             return false;
        }
            // otras comparaciones
        }

        public static Circulo elMayor(Circulo c1,Circulo c2) {
        if(c1.height > c2.height && c1.width > c2.width && c1.radio > c2.radio) {
             return c1;
           } else {
             return c2;
        }
        }

    }
```

El primer método, que es un método de instancia(el cúal podes usar solamente con instancias de la clase `Circulo`) devuelve `true` si `c1` es mayor a `c2`. Ahora bien, también pasa que la clase `Circulo` tiene un método de clase, que bien podes usarlo sin instanciar ningún objeto para usar el método, aunque obviamente, tenés que tener las dos instancias de los circulos a comparar... El segundo método fijate que devuelve un `Circulo`, es decir, va a devolver la instancia mas grande que le hayas pasado. De la otra forma, devolver un `boolean` no hubiese tenido mucho sentido.

```
Circulo c1 = new Circulo(100,100,100,100);
Circulo c2 = new Circulo(50,50,50,50);

c1.elMayor(c2);//Devuelve true.
c2.elMayor(c1);//Devuelve false.
Circulo circuloMasGrande = Circulo.elMayor(c1,c2);//Devuelve referencia a c1
```

Comment: Gracias Mati. Tu respuesta es correcta, y muy bien explicada, te agradezco tu ayuda, he marcado la de Mitsu como correcta porque respondió con una respuesta correcta también antes que tu. Pero como te digo tu respuesta es correcta y también muy aclaratoria.

Comment: Denadaa!, si le pudieses dar una flecha para arriba te lo agradecería de nuevo :P

Answer (score 1):

La primera instrucción indica que todo objeto `Circulo` tiene un método de instancia llamado `elMayor` que recibe otro objeto `Circulo`.

```
public class Circulo {
    private double height;
    private double width;
    private double radio;

    ...

    public int elMayor(Circulo c) {
        // comparar propiedades
        if(this.height < c.height && this.width < c.width && this.radio < c.radio) {
            return -1;
        }
        // otras comparaciones
    }
}
```

La segunda forma el objeto `Circulo` tiene un método de clase, es decir, **estático**.

```
public class Circulo {
    // propiedades

    public static int elMayor(Circulo c1, Circulo c2) {
        // comparar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A)  El paradigma básico en Java es que se escribe `clases` y que esas clases se crean `instancias.` objetos instanciados (una instancia de una clase) tienen atributos asociados a ellos (variables miembro) que afectan su comportamiento; cuando la instancia posee un método en tiempo  de ejecución se hará referencia a estas variables.

En su clase Círculo tendrá algo como esto 
`public Círculo Mayor(Círculo  n1) {...}`

B) Sin embargo, todos los objetos de un tipo particular podrían tener un comportamiento que no depende en absoluto de las variables miembro; estos métodos `státic.`  Al ser estática, no se requiere instancia de la clase para ejecutar el método

En su clase Círculo tendrá algo como esto 
`public static Circulo  esMayor(Circulo no, Circulo  n2) {...}`

Comment: Gracias Dev. Tu respuesta es correcta, te la agradezco pero he marcado correcta la de Mitsu Gami porque respondió antes.

Comment: @OscarC. puedes cambiar la decisión de la respuesta aceptada cuando gustes. Se recomienda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que a ti te parezca mejor, no necesariamente porque se publicó primero o antes.

Comment: Gracias, lo he hecho ahora mismo, pues considero que otra respuesta era más completa, pero no sabía que se podría marcar aunque no fuese la primera. Gracias por la aclaración.